# Simple console.log not working in ASP file

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

The specific issue I'm trying to solve is that there are two buttons that have seemingly lost their functionality. When I went to test if their jQuery was even working, I discovered that I wasn't even getting anything in the console. I'm at a bit of a loss. Here's the code. It's not mine. My boss just died and I'm now the only one with any knowledge of his apps. I am EXTREMELY new to JS and ASP, so I could be missing something entirely simple, but I have a deadline to meet. I have a hunch the two issues are related.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/DairyMaster.Master" CodeBehind="Irrigation.aspx.vb" Inherits="Dairy2.Irrigation" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="Headers" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/date.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        console.log('1234');
        $(window).load(function () {
            console.log('TESTING');

            //variable to reference window 
            $myWindow = jQuery('#dialog');
            $myWindow2 = jQuery('#dialog2');

            //instantiate the dialog 
            $myWindow.dialog({ 
                height: 300,
                width: 500,
                modal: false,
                position: 'center',
                autoOpen: false,
                resizable: false,
                dialogClass: 'TotGalDialog',
                title: 'GPM - Total Gallons Calculator'
            });

            $myWindow2.dialog({ 
                height: 300,
                width: 500,
                modal: false,
                position: 'center',
                autoOpen: false,
                resizable: false,
                dialogClass: 'TotGalDialog',
                title: 'Flow Meter - Total Gallons Calculator'
            });

            $('#btnCalculator').click(showDialog);
            $('#btnCalculator2').click(showDialog2);
    </script>

    <style type="text/css">
    </style>
</asp:Content>
```

This is the top of the file (with extraneous functions removed). Basically, I'm expecting '1234' and/or 'TESTING' to output to the web console, but I'm getting nothing. The '#btnCalculator' and '#btnCalculator2' are specifically what I'm trying to get working, but I figured I'd test if the jQuery was even executing, hence the console.log. Let me know if you need the vb code too.

ANYTHING is appreciated.

Comment: Does the "Network" section of the browser developer tools give any hints, e.g. a 404 response for where it should be loading jQuery?

Comment: Your first `console.log('1234)` does not require jQuery to work, since it's outside of any JavaScript referencing `jQuery` or `$`. Are you seeing any JavaScript errors in your console for this page?

Comment: @AndrewMorton As far as I can see, everything that is loading is loading successfully. I don't see any 404s or other errors. Everything is status 200.

Comment: @EdLucas No errors in the console. There's nothing in the console for this page.

Comment: This sounds bizarre. Basic test: check the View Source of the page in your browser, and double-check that this JavaScript is even present in the page. asp.net webforms' Content blocks could be playing a part in what gets rendered.

Comment: @hunt3rr Can you try in a different browser? Is there any record of anything being changed just before the buttons stopped working, e.g. in the comments for a commit in source control?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Unfortunately, this has probably been broken for a year, but the tool is used VERY infrequently. My boss did an update shortly before I was hired that hosed a lot of things (a year ago). He was fixing them reactively, when someone would bring up that something was broken. He was JUST getting me acquainted with the system when he passed. Just tried it in I.E. as well and same issue.

Comment: @ADyson This is what I see for webforms:

<script src="Scripts/WebForms/MsAjax/MicrosoftAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/WebForms/MsAjax/MicrosoftAjaxWebForms.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: @hunt3rr that's not really what I was asking. I was asking whether the specific bit of JavaScript you're asking about in the question actually gets rendered to your browser. That's what you need to look for - because, if it isn't there, that would go a long way to explaining why it doesn't execute! :-)

Comment: @hunt3rr P.S. regarding Andrew Morton's point...just because the update was a long time ago doesn't mean there might not be any clues in the source control history. Have you looked at the history of changes on the file in question?

Comment: @ADyson Ah I see what you mean. Yeah the specific console.log() statement(s) are not anywhere in the page source, which seems problematic. I'll see if I can find any sort of version control. When I built this project for the first time, my boss didn't have it in any version control that I could pull from. He had to create a GitHub just so I could pull the project. The only local history I have on the specific file is from March, but that's when the file was "created" on my machine.

Comment: "specific console.log() statement(s) are not anywhere in the page source, which seems problematic"...ok so you need to find out why it's not being rendered. If the entire block of Javascript you've shown isn't there I'd guess it's maybe because the `<asp:Content` block it's within isn't being rendered by asp.net. That in turn might be because there's no `<asp:contentplaceholder` with a matching ContentPlaceHolderID in the master page. (See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.content?view=netframework-4.8 for more info on how the content system works)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215624/discussion-between-hunt3rr-and-adyson).